# Building WKB from geometry using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, well-known-binary

I have some points in an array,stored by user click on the map in ArcMap,and I want to build a polyline and create a Well Known Binary sequence.

I use IPointCollection interface to add this points to Polyline object,and when I draw this polyline,it shows line successfully but the function
"CreateWkbVariantFromGeometry" returns E_OUTOFMEMORY error when I pass this geometry into it.What's wrong with this method for creating a plolyline?

```
IPolylinePtr ipPL(CLSID_Polyline);

IPointCollectionPtr ipPC;

if(ipPL->QueryInterface(IID_IPointCollection,(void**)&ipPC)!=S_OK)
        return E_FAIL;
for(int i=0;i<myPointCount;i++)
{
    IPointPtr ipP=this->GetPoint(i);
    if(this->m_ipDispTrn->ToMapPoint(this->m_Points[i].x,this->m_Points[i].y,&ipP)!=S_OK)
        return E_FAIL;
    if(ipPC->AddPoint(ipP)!=S_OK)
        return E_FAIL;
}
IGeometryPtr ipG;
if(ipPL->QueryInterface(IID_IGeometry,(void**)&ipG)!=S_OK)
    return E_FAIL;

//.Drawing line on the screen catch . ipS is a SimpleLineSymbol object
//....................................................StartDrawing here
this->m_ipSDisplay->SetSymbol(ipS);
if(this->m_ipSDisplay->DrawPolyline(ipG)=S_OK)//This line works successfully
    return E_FAIL;
//....................................................FinishDrawing here

//.Building WKB from geometry
IGeometryFactory2Ptr ipGF;
IGeometryEnvironmentPtr ipGE(CLSID_GeometryEnvironment);
if(ipGE->QueryInterface(IID_IGeometryFactory2,(void**)&ipGF)!=S_OK)
    return E_FAIL;
VARIANT var;
HRESULT hr=ipGF->CreateWkbVariantFromGeometry(ipG,&var);//hr=E_OUTOFMEMORY
if(hr!=S_OK)
    return E_FAIL;
```

Comment: Did you try assiging a spatial reference to both the polyline as well as each point (ipP) that you add to it first?

Comment: yes Kirk,after your comment,I added spatial reference to both points and line,but not working properly.Then I build 2 point simple lines(ILine) as segments with each points pair([0,1],[1,2],[2,3],..) and built a polyline using ISegmentCollection,but not working again.I'm sure there is a problem with the method I build polyline,but I don't know why IScreenDisplay::DrawPolyline can work with it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a much easier solution. Just QI to IWKB and use the ExportToWkb method. This is an extract of the arcobjects driver I wrote for GDAL:

```
  HRESULT hr;

  esriGeometry::IWkbPtr ipWkb = pInAOGeo;

  long reqSize = 0;

  if (FAILED(hr = ipWkb->get_WkbSize(&reqSize)))
  {
    AOErr(hr, "Error getting Wkb buffer size");
    return false;
  }

  if (reqSize > inOutBufferSize)
  {
    // resize working buffer
    delete [] pInOutWorkingBuffer;
    pInOutWorkingBuffer = new unsigned char[reqSize];
    inOutBufferSize = reqSize;
  }

  if (FAILED(hr = ipWkb->ExportToWkb(&reqSize, pInOutWorkingBuffer)))
  {
    AOErr(hr, "Error exporting to WKB buffer");
    return false;
  }
```

You can find the complete code in the [GDAL SVN](https://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/arcobjects/aoutils.cpp). I know it works, so hopefully this helps...